# Difference Between 2 Dates (number of hours beyond 24 hours)

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date

Trying to get some working syntax for calculating the difference in hours between 2 dates, Start Date [9am] and Due Date [5pm] for example.

```
=TEXT([Due Date]-[Start Date],"h")
```

This yields the correct hourly difference when both dates are on the same day.

However I need the formula to take the full difference into account!

```
=(IF(AND((WEEKDAY(B2,2))<(WEEKDAY(A2,2)),((WEEKDAY(A2,2))-(WEEKDAY(B2,2)))>1),(((DATEDIF(A2,B2,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(A2,B2,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF(A2,B2,"D")+1))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF(A2,B2,"D")+1)/7,1)*2)))-1)*8+((TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2), SECOND(B2))-TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2), SECOND(A2)))*24)
```

This is the syntax from a previous question, I've tried adapting it to my column names but i'm not sure if this is the correct formula to use or not.

My regional settings have the work day set to 8am til 5pm (9hrs) working day (Mon-Fri)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My regional settings have the work day set to 8am til 5pm (9hrs) working day (Mon-Fri)

This will have no impact on a Calculated Column.

**To find working hours excluding weekends and assuming a work day from 8AM to 5PM (9 hours) then:**

```
=(INT([Due Date])-INT([Start Date])+1)*9 
 + IF( INT([Due Date])<INT([Start Date])+5-WEEKDAY([Start Date],3),
       0,
       -FLOOR( ((INT([Due Date])-INT([Start Date]))+1 )/7,1) * 2 * 9 )
 -(([Start Date]-INT([Start Date]))*24-8)
 -(17-([Due Date]-INT([Due Date]))*24)
```

This assumes all entries are M-F between the hours of 9 and 5. It does not work correctly for weekend dates or hours outside of 9 to 5.

[image]

**To find working hours excluding weekends and assuming a work day from 9AM to 5PM (8 hours) then:**

```
=(INT([Due Date])-INT([Start Date])+1) * 8 
 + IF( INT([Due Date])<INT([Start Date])+5-WEEKDAY([Start Date],3),
       0,
       -FLOOR( ((INT([Due Date])-INT([Start Date]))+1 )/7,1) * 2 * 8 )
 -(([Start Date]-INT([Start Date]))*24-9)
 -(17-([Due Date]-INT([Due Date]))*24)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply. I've clarified my question as i'm trying to find the exact hourly difference based between 2 dates and not the number of 24 hours periods between 2 dates. And those hours are based on the 9am start and 5pm end. So each day is a 9 hour working day.

Comment: I have updated the answer above.

Comment: Much appreciated Mike, that's one gorgeous formula! Thank you.

Comment: Jim, I've been working on a book and a series of blog articles on Calculated Columns, so I've been getting a little practice in writing these... :-)  Months, Working days and Hours are the most challenging.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the total hours between two times, using the following formula:

=INT(([Column2]-[Column1])*24)

Reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)

Comment: Hi Lisa, appreciate the help. I've clarified my question a bit more as im not looking for the number of 24 hours periods but the actual difference in hours between the 2 timestamped dates. And those hours are based on the 9am start and 5pm end. So each day is a 9 hour working day.